# Sum of two binomial variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I'm quite not sure how can I show that a sum of two binomial variables with different probability for success is NOT binomial. Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assume $X_i \sim \text{Binomial}(n_i, p_i)$ and they are independent. First note that the support of $X_1 + X_2$ is $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n_1 + n_2\}$, then you may check $\Pr\{X_1 + X_2 = 0\} = \Pr\{X_1 = 0, X_2 = 0\} = (1 - p_1)^{n_1}(1 - p_2)^{n_2}$ and $\Pr\{X_1 + X_2 = n_1 + n_2\} = \Pr\{X_1 = n_1, X_2 = n_2\} = p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they are independent, if they were distributed $\text{Binomial}(n_1, p_1)$ and $\text{Binomial}(n_2, p_2)$ and the sum were $\text{Binomial}(n_3, p_3)$ you would need

- $n_3=n_1+n_2$ to match the support (assuming $p_1>0$ and $p_2 \gt 0$)
- $n_3p_3 = n_1p_1+n_2p_2 $ to match the mean
- $n_3p_3(1-p_3) = n_1p_1(1-p_1)+n_2p_2(1-p_2)$ to match the variance

This gives three equations in the two unknowns $n_3$ and $p_3$, which would give inconsistent results unless $p_1=p_2$ or $n_1=0$ or $n_2=0$

Comment: why it would give inconsistent results?

Comment: @PedroHenrique - if you substitute $n_3=n_1+n_2$ into the second equation you get $p_3= \dfrac{n_1p_1+n_2p_2}{n_1+n_2}$. If you then substitute both into the third equation and rearrange, you get $\dfrac{n_1 n_2 {{\left( p_2-p_1\right) }^{2}}}{n_1+n_2} =0$ which is not true except in the special cases mentioned